# Override Scss Variable value when body direction rtl

Tags: css, angular, sass

I want to Override Scss Variable value when body direction rtl. I tried like below but its not working. Actually I have used $FONT_REGULAR variable in lot of components, For English version it is ok but now we want to change the font in arabic version but its not working.

```
$FONT_REGULAR: "Roboto-Regular";

body[dir='rtl'] {
$FONT_REGULAR: "FSAlbertArabicWeb-Regular";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
html[dir='rtl']
{
  // Write here...
}
```